# Rerender a specific region/block/div in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm coming from a richfaces background, and in richfaces it was possible to rerender a specific region. I'm hearing its possible in Symfony2 as well but all the examples and documentation I'm reading don't seem to help me. Can somebody point me in the right direction for what i'm trying to do?

Basically I have a div tag containing information about the user (address, zip code, etc.). If  they click 'edit', it should re render that div, and replace all that information with a form that can be used to edit that information on the user. I know in richfaces this was a basic use case, is this possible in Symfony2? If so, is there a link with proper documenatation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this by both details and form block and toggling display based on edit/cancel action. If  the form block is in another twig template file then you can load it in controller by following way,

```
$formBlock = $this->get('twig')->loadTemplate("VendorBundle:Location:your_form_template.html.twig")->renderBlock('your_form_block', array('form' => $form->createView()));
```

And then pass it to the view.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same. I guess I'll do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Richfaces is a purely GUI-component framework, unfortunately symfony is a MVC-web-application-framework. If you search something compareable you might need to search for a component framework for symfony, which is capable of this. I do not know such components for symfony 2.